# Send mail on postgres 8.4 using SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, send, postgresql-8.4

I would like to Send mail on postgres 8.4 using SMTP using Gmail mail server and my username and password

Answer (score 0):

Postgres direct is not able to send out mails (at least none I know of). But you could write an extension doing this. Personally I'd try to use Python with pl/python for doing this.

Python: http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

pl/python in PostgreSQL 8.4: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpython.html